# Trim SelectedItem ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, trim

I have this comboBox items:

```
A6 - Tiger
A79 - Eagle
B6789- Elephant
B69679 - Monkey
C67 - Whale
D - Dragon
```

How I could show the selectedItem into textBox with only the strings Tiger, Eagle Elephant... without the A6, A79, B6789 ??

I used this when working on a fixed number of char:

```
string temp = comboBox1.Text;
char[] array1 = temp.ToCharArray();
textBox1.Text = "" + array1[0] + array1[1];
```

Comment: `temp.Split("-")[1].Trim()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that "A6 - Tiger" is the format of you texts.

You could try this:

```
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            textBox1.Text = comboBox1.Text.Substring(comboBox1.Text.IndexOf('-') + 1).Trim();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the `SelectedItem`:

```
textBox1.Text = theSelectedItem.Split('-')[1].Trim()
```

Comment: I assumed his `temp` was his item he wanted printing :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to me like you want to show only the A6, A79, B6789,...
so I post the solution for both

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{//Last
    string s = (string)listBox1.SelectedItem;

    string last = s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1);

    textBox1.Text = last;

    listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_first(sender, e);
}


private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{//First
    string s = (string)listBox1.SelectedItem;
    string first = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(' '));

    textBox1.Text = first;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
  string[] splittedValues =  comboBox1.Text.Trim().Split('-');
  if(splittedValues.Length==2)
      textBox1.Text = splittedValues[1].Trim();
```